# What is intrinsic in Capitalism which leads to accumulation of wealth with a minority?

Tags: capitalism

I know this is a broad question some would recommend me reading Marx or other critics of capitalism to find the answer.

But my question is, in almost all western world, there are left wing entities in government which try to 'amend' the system, but despite all those measures by 'left wing' entities (consider these left entities as spectrum from center left to extreme left), one thing in which systems in western nations have failed miserably: i.e., stop the accumulation of wealth. Yes, the quality of life of ordinary man has gone better as compared to one century before, but from Korea to US, Germany to Australia, gap between rich and poor is getting wider and wider.

I want to ask, is this polarization of wealth a natural corollary of capitalism? If yes, then what is that thing which, despite 'measures' by center-left/socialist/left parties - this problem- instead of receding, is getting worse and worse?

Comment: A Marxist perspective would say that the inherent infrastructure of capitalism (capitalists and workers, the motivation to pursue profit, etc) is what keeps wealth disparity continual. In a strong sense, the concept of maximizing profit being the goal of the capitalists (those who dole wages out to workers and own the means of production) is what continues to drive wealth inequality. The intrinsic aspect is the infrastructure of the system itself.

Comment: @Not_Here 'motivation to pursue profit', isn't it ingrained in every human being by default? I mean which human being performs an action where his motivation is not to pursue his profit/interest. Even where he/she apparently works for other's profits selflessly e.g. risking one's life to rescue someone, it is for the sake of some ideals or values. He would not perform any of these heroic/selfless acts, if he did not derive from them a specific pleasure and a benefit which outweighs the loss resulting from (a)his love for another human being, ..

Comment: , or (b) from his sacrifice for the sake of some of the ideals in which he believed. So if this 'motivation to pursue (his/her own) profit/interest' is so inherent in every human being, how can this be a flaw in capitalism?

Comment: When two people walk up to a door at the same time and one of the people lets the other person go first, they are not acting in their own self interest or pursuing their own profits. When you see someone who needs help and you help them out of empathy, you are not acting in your own self interest or out of motivation to maximize profits. People act selflessly all the time. Motivation to maximize profits is *intrinsic* to the structure of capitalism as a system, which is what you asked, not whether or not people are inherently selfish.

Comment: @Not_Here I think I was unable to clear my point. First what is meant by profit/interest? When I talk about interest, it does not have to be money or something material (-istic) or sensuous, interest can be non-sensuous as well. When 1 person lets other to pass the door first, it is because he derives a pleasure/benefit while doing/sacrificing something for other and he believes that this pleasure is more worthy than the impression which will generate if he does not do so. So in this way, all human beings are 'selfish', what matters is, how they define or develop their 'self-interest'?

Comment: "Motivation to maximize profits is *intrinsic* to the structure of capitalism as a system"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79187/discussion-between-not-here-and-ather-cheema).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surplus_value We find inequality drives crime rates, health problems and many other issues https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6304389-the-spirit-level Historically wars and disasters like the black death have been major drivers of increased equality

Comment: I would say it's not capitalism itself that leads to such wealth distribution. People themselves are a cause for this. Those people who strive for wealth. I think it'd be much better if personal wealth has been measured by percentage of overall wealth instead of currency.

Comment: Some people are better at making money than others, and those who are best at it will always be in a minority.

Comment: This principle has nothing to do with 'capitalism', everything to do with human nature. Genetically, the ability of human beings exists on a spectrum. Those with talent and the ability to exploit niche's for profit will accumulate more money. Those with more money end up making even more money. Regardless of economic implementation, this will always be true.

Comment: First and foremost probably the fact that it already started with a social, political and economic inequality and didn't really consider all or even worse any of them to be a problem in the first place. And from there probably the mode of production which perpetuates and intensifies that. The classical mode of production under capitalism is as follows, the capitalist invest money to buy stuff and hire people to produce a commodity (good or service that is fungible and only made for trade not consumption by the capitalist). With the intent that the sale of the commodity makes more than the cost

Comment: @CriglCragl Wars and plagues: the great Equalizers. Famine not so much.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Depends on the causes & solutions. Managing floods, & irrigation, have been major drivers of human cooperation & civilisational prosperity. See also the Cuban 'Special Period', the 3 years after they lost patronage from the USSR. It is interesting to look at how cultures in hostile environments generally have elaborate hospitality & friendliness to strangers. Being reminded there are more hostile things than each other builds solidarity..

Comment: @CriglCragl Thank you. It would be great if *everyone* would bear in mind how hostile the universe at large is to life, and everything really, and be more hospitable. Our good fortune in even drawing breath, let alone having civilization, is astonishing. But, we are ungrateful.

Comment: "Under the windings of the sea
They lying long shall not die windily;
Twisting on racks when sinews give way,
Strapped to a wheel, yet they shall not break;
Faith in their hands shall snap in two,
And the unicorn evils run them through;
Split all ends up they shan't crack;
And death shall have no dominion.

And death shall have no dominion.
No more may gulls cry at their ears
Or waves break loud on the seashores;
Where blew a flower may a flower no more
Lift its head to the blows of the rain;
Though they be mad and dead as nails,
Heads of the characters hammer through daisies"

Comment: @ScottRowe: "I want to be better than oxygen
So you can breathe when you're drowning and weak in the knees
I want to speak louder than Ritalin
For all the children who think that they've got a disease
I want to be cooler than t.v.
For all the kids that are wondering what they are going to be
We can be stronger than bombs
If you're singing along and you know that you really believe
We can be richer than industry
As long as we know that there's things that we don't really need" https://youtu.be/RvZIiiIMwbg

Comment: "Can I suggest u're c'in x'tly what they want u to c A monster cancer threat to ur liberty. How 'bout a scapegoat for their crimes, a victim of the times Evthing that ur not meant 2b How 'bout a badly prepared scared human b'in How about a necessary cog in their economic machine If there was no unemployment tell me how would things b Would you still feel lucky to b workin 40 hrs a week Like a caged bird & they got us by the beak
Give us enuf to eat enuf 2 sleep enuf 2 tweet But there's not enuf space btween the ground & our feet We're singing songs of freedom but we're not flying free"

Comment: @CriglCragl Integrity.

Answer (score 6):

Very roughly, a Marxist viewpoint would hold that inequality is intrinsic to capitalism since capitalism is a system in which the means of production are privately owned and are used to make profits for their owners. Profits derive from selling the products of labour, employed to operate the means of production, at a higher price than is paid to that labour : this is the extraction of surplus value. A far more refined and nuanced statement is possible and I leave this to others. What I want to suggest here, basing myself on the work of Geoffrey Hughes, is that there are sources of inequality in capitalism, turning on 'complexity', which apply independently of a Marxist analysis.

**Capitalism, complexity, and inequality**

> Capitalism is a social formation in which markets and commodity production are
>    pervasive, including capital markets and labor markets. ... Its driving logic involves the expansion and diversification of multiple markets. As it expands, corporations seek ever-new opportunities
>    for trade and gain. As competition intensifies within particular markets, profit-seeking
>    corporations innovate and diversify their products in unceasing creation of new market
>    niches (Chamberlin 1933; Rueschemeyer 1986). The competitive pursuit of profit pressures firms to invest in new technology or new skills. In this quest for innovation, the
>    frontiers of science and technology are advanced, leading to new fields of knowledge
>    and enquiry. Services are generally more diverse than manufactured goods; hence,
>    diversity also increases with the increasing relative size of the service sector. New and varied organizational forms are devised to increase productivity and to manage an
>    exponentially expanding number of products and processes.
>
> Accordingly, there is a long-run tendency in capitalist economic systems toward
>    greater complexity, driven by powerful economic forces and leading to the widening of markets and greater product diversification (Warsh 1985). There are several meanings
>    of complexity and the definition of complexity is problematic (Pryor 1996; Rosser
>    199-9), but we can make an outline attempt. Complexity is not the same as variety
>    (Saviotti 1996). Variety refers to a diversity of types. Complexity exists only when such
>    variety exists within a structured system. In short, complexity in the sense used here is
>    systemically interconnected and interactive variety. By this definition, increasing economic
>    complexity means a growing diversity of interactions between human beings and
>    between people and their technology...
>
> The increasing diversity of products and tasks, along with the growing sophistication of knowledge, is likely to be paralleled with an increasing variety of skills and occupations. As complexity grows within the economic system, it is likely that there will be  demands for higher and higher levels of skill in particular specialisms. New specialisms
>    emerge to deal with the multiplying facets of the increasingly complex capitalist system.
>    Workers with advanced and transferable skills, and with enhanced capacities to rapidly
>    learn and adapt, are more and more at a premium. We have a scenario of enhanced
>    skills and growing knowledge intensity.
>    Some skills and professions will become obsolete. At the same time, for each individual worker, it becomes more difficult and costly to transfer readily from one specialism to another. A skills escalator can emerge, where frequent retraining is required to
>    relocate in the more skilled and more highly remunerative jobs. Retraining is easier and
>    less risky for those that already have acquired high skill levels. Without remedial policies
>    and subsidies, some may never get onto the skills escalator. A further widening of inequality can result. (Geoffrey M. Hodgson, 'Capitalism, Complexity, and Inequality', Journal of Economic Issues, Vol. 37, No. 2 (Jun., 2003), pp. 471-478 : 471-2, 474-5.)

Introducing increasing complexity into the picture fits both with Marxist analysis and with an explanation independent of Marxism.

**References**

Chamberlin, Edward H. The Theory of Monopolistic Competition. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, 1933.

Hodgson, Geoffrey M. 'Capitalism, Complexity, and Inequality', Journal of Economic Issues, Vol. 37, No. 2 (Jun., 2003), pp. 471-478.

Pryor, Frederic L. Economic Evolution and Structure: The Impact of Complexity on the U.S. Economic System. Cambridge and New York: Cambridge University Press, 1996.

Pryor, Frederic L., and David L. Schafer. Who's Not Working and Why. Cambridge: Cambridge UniveTsity Press, 1999.

Rosser, J. Barkley, Jr. "On the Complexities of Complex Economic Dynamics." Journal of Economic Perspectives, 13, no. 4 (fall 1999): 169-192.

Rueschemeyer, Dietrich. Power and the Division of Labor. Stanford, Calif.: Stanford University Press, 1986.

Saviotti, Pier Paolo. Technological Evolution, Variety, and the Economy. Aldershot, U.K.: Edward Elgar, 1996.

Answer (score 4):

I pose two postulates:

1. The more wealth you have, the easier it is to accumulate wealth
2. The total potential to accumulate wealth exceeds the rate at which the available wealth grows

The first point means that, on average, the gap in wealth between people will tend to grow over time.

The second point implies a competition which, I think, tends to shape the distribution of wealth so that there are fewer high-wealth people.

Comment: Re your postulate 2. The total wealth of the world has grown exponentially for about 2 centuries.  https://reason.com/2016/12/13/the-most-important-graph-in-the-world/  Total wealth has been increased by capitalism far more than any small group of wealthy people.

Comment: This notion is discussed at length in the popular book 'Capital in the Twenty-First Century', by Thomas Picketty, which the asker may be interested in.

@BillOnne, while the economy has grown exponentially, the rate of return on capital being a percentage means that wealth grows exponentially too. An economy growing by 0.1% per year is still exponential, but if the rich are doubling their wealth every year as well you're going to have some serious inequality developing

Comment: You make up data and ignore the data I posted in my answer. Inequality over the last two centuries has very mildly decreased. This is primarily due to the poorest catching up.

Answer (score 3):

I have another psychological approach which is that **capitalism encourages non-empathetic behaviour**.

When morality and ethics are a problem to most people those individuals with no remorse nor ethics who are good at emulating to have them are rewarded because in capitalism **morality is expensive**.

Take for instance drugs companies who won't research cure to diseases because they are making large profits out them. Or any other human experience or sensation you can think of such as the business of sex, entertainment, justice, education, health, prisons, military contractors, mainstream media, politicians, war, pitty and sadness etc. All those don't always have morality nor common interest in mind and if some changes are made in society they could go out of business.

The amount of sociopaths, psychopaths and greedy narcissists is small compared to ordinary people. 
Selling your ethics for wealth is not new:

> Matthew 4:8 ...the devil took him to a very high mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory. “All this I will give You,” he said, “if You will fall down and worship me.”…

Comment: The people more able to grow their property at a rate faster than others will continue to do so.  It's basically a compound interest problem; compare somebody with 20% growth to somebody with 5% growth, after forty years.

Comment: In order for this answer to have any merit you would have to somehow demonstrate that those people who have accumulated a lot of wealth are non-empathetic, immoral and unethical but are good at emulating the opposite. Let alone your implication that wealthy people are sociopaths, psychopaths and greedy narcissists. As for capitalism enocourages non-empathetic behavior...I can just as validly as you make the same claim with regards to communism and socialism as under those systems everyone is encouraged to be treated identically. They aren't human, just another identical part of the collective

Comment: @Dunk there is nothing to demonstrate when you are using pure logic. Perhaps those socialists/communists systems you talk about where not that social after all but that's another debate.

Comment: @PbxMan-I am not claiming what I said in my comment is true or not. I was simply pointing out that it is fine to state an opinion but please attempt to back it up with some sort of logic, reasoning or evidence. Otherwise, someone can make the opposite claim, without providing anything supporting that claim and whose to say which position is more reasonable? People will just agree with the  position that is more like theirs and not learn a thing.

Comment: @Dunk again... My logic is on the second paragraph. Sometimes when the mind doesn't notice something it's because deep down we don't want to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Think of any [board](https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Browse/Search:economics%20board%20game) [game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) that uses a resource management mechanic... at the beginning of the game, everyone starts with the same exact quantity of resources, and by the end of the game, some have (through a combination of luck, strategy, and tactics) accumulated more resources than others.

In such a game, those who are losing have thinner and thinner margins for error as the game goes on. Any mistake in strategy or poor roll of the dice will wipe out larger and larger percentages of their available resources. Conversely, those who are winning have wider and wider margins of error... losses that would wipe out other players in a single round can be recovered in future rounds because there's more cushion.

Let's add a cooperation mechanic to the game, so that players can agree to combine resources in order to gain more resources. The players with fewer resources will find it difficult to participate... they may not have the minimum resources required, and they are in a weaker bargaining position when it comes to negotiating payouts. So the players with more resources will tend to cooperate with each other.

Let's add another mechanic -- new players can be invited into the game by current players. New players start with resources that are given to them by the player who invited them. Players with more resources can afford to give more resources to new players. New players will start in a position determined by who invited them into the game, so some players will be invited and start with more resources than existing players.

Let's add a rent mechanic to the game. Players can corner the market on certain resources, and other players will be forced to pay part of their resources to the player who holds that resource in order to stay in the game. The players who are charging rent will, of course, gain resources in excess of the cost of holding the resource. In addition, they can give such revenue generating resources to new players who they invite into the game.

Now we have a situation where new players are invited into the game, and some of those players start the game with the ability to collect resources from other new players, and some players start the game needing to pay resources to other players in order just to stay in the game.

Is it possible to gain a large number of resources in such a game, if you start out the game losing? Of course. All you need is near perfect play and good luck. Is it possible to lose a large number of resources in such a game? Of course. All you need is terrible play and a lot of bad luck. But if you start the game with a rent generating resource, you can keep winning without putting much effort into the game at all.

Capitalism is a resource management game that never ends, where those who are winning write the rules, and the only way to quit is death.

Comment: Otherwise known as "proof by boardgame." Monopoly(TM) is not a reasonable model for reality.

Comment: @BillOnne While I appreciate your assertion that you don't like my metaphor, I don't see an actual critique of it. You are correct that the board game you mentioned is a poor economic model, but it also lacks almost every mechanic I described.

Comment: On the contrary. Except for adding new players in the middle, the boardgame has all of your mechanics. Quite explicitly and deliberately, since the game was designed to produce the wrenching experience of going broke for all but one person.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)#History And yet, in a capitalism, very few people actually wind up irretrievably broke.

Comment: @BillOnne there is no way to combine resources to unlock new resources in monopoly. There is no way to add new players in monopoly. It's a pure rent-seeking game, with very weak resource management mechanics and almost no strategy or tactics. And that aside, you still aren't actually offering a critique.

Comment: @BillOnne or to put it less nicely: you are correct that that specific game is a poor model for an economy. Do you have a relevant comment to make?

Comment: Did you ever actually play Monopoly? Combining resources is called creating a monopoly, and it unlocks houses and then hotels. There are loads of tactics and strategies. They are all channeled, quite explicitly and deliberately, as reported by the authors of the game, to produce the cascade failure that ends the game. And it was *you* who put boardgames into your answer.

Comment: @BillOnne What is your point here? Like yes Monopoly was intended less as a "game" and more as a simulation or rather demonstration of a mechanic of a capitalist economy. And it does it's job quite well to drive home the point how this mechanic leads to unequal distribution up to annihilation of competitors and monopoly positions. Now it explicitly avoids  mitigating this feature, but that doesn't mean that the mechanic and it's result aren't still connected and that this mechanic is still legal and active in the current system and has similar results because of it, right?

Comment: @BillOnne Rent seeking and achieving monopolies are still the wet dream of any business person. It's still at the heart of the system and you can argue that it already has several times ended in catastrophes, revolutions, civil wars and whatnot and that the fact that it doesn't constantly do so is due to active measures trying to mitigate that. Also no in Monopoly there is 2 resources, money and means of producing money and those are fixed so you can't add ways to make money at least not within the game.

Comment: @BillOnne Yes. I have played monopoly. Two players cannot combine their resources in monopoly. It is a poor model of an actual economy. Did you have anything relevant to say, or are you just going to keep referring to a fairly unsophisticated board game as if that somehow makes a point?

Comment: @philosodad What would it change if you changed the rules so that 2 players could combine their resources? I mean you wouldn't alter the concept you'd just reduce the number of players like PlayerA and PlayerB would now be called PlayerC but the concept stays pretty much the same.

Comment: @haxor789 it would change it enormously. For example, if Player A held one red and one blue property, and Player B and Player C held two of each, Player A could hold the properties and form two corporations with B and C, developing both blue and red. Adding corporations changes the game a great deal, especially when playing with a large number of players.

Comment: @philosodad Well that massively depends on how you deal with that. Like you could argue that A can only collect on their property or split revenue 33:66 rather than 50/50. Or have them sill pay each other respectively when coming on the property just that it's half the price instead of the full one. Your idea seems to be that the weaker link in a key position has 2 developed properties where the other 2 bust their asses while he's safe on them, but that doesn't need to be the result of the negotiation does it?

Comment: @haxor789 precisely. You just brought up a ton of issues and questions that don't exist without the mechanic. Those new issues, potential new rules, or contract requirements are an enormous change to the game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138952/discussion-between-haxor789-and-philosodad).

Comment: "*The problem with the Rat Race is, even if you win, you're still a rat.*"

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Capitalism is to create wealth for the ones in power to do so. Everything else from an objective p.o.v is secondary towards irrelevant compared to that purpose, human life included. Everything else from a general p.o.v. is propaganda (**1 will detail below*).

The tendency of such a system can be interpreted mathematically and it manifested like it was planned, meaning in plain English that more and more wealth will be in the hands of less and less people. It was, is and always will be inevitable. (Rule of Acquisition 010: Greed is eternal, Rule of Acquisition 182: The cost for profit is never too high.)

Currently (actually since about 3 years ago), we got to the point that in the U.S. the **top 1% own more wealth than the bottom 95%**, and between them stands a buffer of about 4%.

In time, the 1% will become 1:1000, the 95% will become 99% and the rest of under 1% will be the buffer. (**1:detail* - none whatsoever will ever be able to reach top 1% unless selected, trained, formatted and approved by the ones currently in that top 1%).

The only issue relevant here is what actually happens when the wealth distribution becomes so unbalanced that will lead to a collapse of the system.

Mathematically, the numbers 0.1%, 99% and under 1% are the critical point, which is relatively close, but math is not the only factor.

The top wealthy ones also take complete measures on all aspects to make sure that they stay in power, they grow wealthier, they have the means to protect themselves and their wealth and to oppress everyone that tries anything against them.

So the math-based collapse will not work because the wealthy top controls everything: the actual wealth, the oppressive armed forces (which become more and more armed), the means of trade, the rules (they call laws, which are no longer based on morality), the resources, the top technology, the top knowledge and every other practical aspect of a society. 
In order for the system to re-balance itself, the % difference will have to be larger than the mathematically-anticipated one.

Therefore, the capitalism is quite a bigger failure compared to socialism and will lead inevitably to a more destructive collapse.

To convince yourselves how capitalism actually works, please study [the complete Ferengi rules of acqusition](https://xaeus.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/the-ferengi-rules-of-acquisition-all-known-so-far-en/) and replace the word Latinum with Gold or $ or what currency you prefer and Ferengi with 'a top 1% wealthy person' or anything similar you may find convenient. The rules, as the movies series they appear in, have been created at the supervision of those time's top wealthiest people, which even used extrapolations of technologies which actually were later developed.

So to conclude: the discrepancy will become higher and higher until the system will self-balance by total collapse.

Probably the system that will replace it will be meritocracy, which is another topic.

Comment: I think you are talking more about what calamities unequal distribution of wealth brings with itself and not what causes this inequitable distribution at first place.

Comment: Purpose? You think capitalism is teleological? What about rewards for risk and thrift in allocation of resources. Your doomsday prophecy does not seem borne out anywhere, you might expect the most unequal societies to collapse first, when in general they grow eg. Russia

Comment: As I described, a collapse is more complex to estimate now due to all available control, propaganda and enforcement means.

Comment: @CriglCragl, it is. Adam Smith wrote on it with purpose. Money have been created with purpose. And there are many other teleogical things that allowed capitalism to exist.

Comment: Whether you want to admit it or not, capitalistic ideals has raised the standard of living for nearly everyone in the capitalistic society by a tremendous degree. What your doomsday description fails to take into account is something like this. Using a scale of 1 to 10 (with 10 = better). If no capitalism existed then suppose ordinary person's quality of life increased from 2 to 5 under socialism. However, in capitalistic society, ordinary person's quality went from 2 to 7. But some small percentage went to 10. In which society is 'ordinary person' better off?

Comment: @Dunk I'm not sure that "the peons should be grateful that they aren't starving to death in the streets" is quite the knockout punch you think it is. For example, the fact that *anyone* goes hungry in a society with a surplus of food may be an indicator of a situation worth improving.

Comment: The people in "the 1%" are not the same over time. Especially in a capitalist country. Indeed, very few people remain in this group for more than a few years. Your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: @BillOnne so some people stay in the top 1% for generations, and some do not. A very large group remain in the bottom 50% for generations. Almost no one falls from the top 1% to the bottom 50% in a single generation, and almost no one goes the other way. How is the explanation inaccurate?

Comment: @Dunk -- you left out the percentage whose life value went to zero, due to workplace accidents, and industrial toxification.  Unregulated markets benefit the 1% massively, benefit many of the 99% to a lesser degree, but also dramatically harm some fraction of the 99%.  This is why all democracies adopt mixed/regulated economies, to try to find a middle ground that benefits from the economic growth of capitalism, while addressing the ills that pure capitalism causes.

Comment: Overmind, inequality does not continue increasing infinitely in capitalist systems.  Your model is way too simple, and does not address the history of varying inequality over time and location.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: freedom. It is the same as asking why the best soccer players in the world are so few and there is a huge difference between them and the rest of the soccer players? Well, because in a system that has freedom the best players emerge.

Comment: I made some grammar and style edits to clarify the answer. You are welcome to roll this back or continue editing. One place where I think an edit is needed is to list references to others who take this same position. This would strengthen your answer so it may not be deleted in the future and it would give the reader a place to go for more detailed information.

Comment: Im not talking about the best in the moral sense im talking about the best pursuing a goal

Comment: you are getting out the road, if the goal is being rich yes they are, i am not talking about the 1% im talking about the 99% of course.Yeah maybe factors like geographic location gives some more advantages but we are not  talking about that i am answering the question what makes capitalism to have very small number of people as the richest because they are the best at making money or they are lucky,etc. And i am not talking about what is good or not im talking about why that "behavior" emerges in capitalism.

Comment: A bell shaped distribution among stuff is so prevalent that it's literally called the "normal distribution", but to argue that something is "best" is different. Because that means there is an external condition that makes one set of skill be better equipped for that then another. So being a soccer player on it's own is not terribly good, it's the fact that there are people willing to throw millions at a good soccer player that makes it worthwhile to have that skill. So in capitalism the person with lots of money can selectively breed the rest. So free for few torment for the rest

Comment: So true. Access to nutrition, training, and opportunity has nothing to do with how well someone does on the soccer field over the course of their lifetime. That's why no one pays for private coaches and club teams are free.

Answer (score 0):

Inequality has been part of humanity for a long time, the relevant question is what is the trend on inequality, both recently and historically, and why.

One of the key insights here IS from Marx, and it has to do with surplus profits.  Basically almost every commercial interaction operates with surplus profits for both sides -- in that the same deal could be arrived at with a range of prices.  If either party would walk away if the price point moved by a small amount in the wrong direction, that party has no surplus profit from the deal.

Surplus profits gives all parties flexibility -- they can grant favors in a deal, or outright gifts to others.  Those with NO excess profits, are unable to be generous.  The rest of us are able to be generous, because excess profits appear in almost everything we do.

The first appearance of significant inequality was with the development of agriculture.  With that development, humans became settled, our population grew dramatically, and we developed a ruling class, who granted to themselves the "ownership" of land, which was the major source of wealth.  The ruling class became far more wealthy than working farmers.  Whether this was due to "ownership" or "ruling" is hard to decouple. Most agricultural societies used law to force the working farmers to negotiate at a disadvantage (serf laws, etc) so that the owners/rulers could maximize how much of that excess profit they could pocket.  Note, profitability had a weak relationship to competence -- inherited landowners had no particular competence, but were inordinately wealthy due to the laws of ownership, and serfdom.

There were a few factories where artisans made pottery, cloth, dye, etc en mass before the industrial age, but those organizations were rare.  A few merchants also became wealthy, basically due to a large return on risk from moving goods place/place.  These were anomalies.  These merchants and artisans were an exception to meritless wealth.  Until recently, the wealthy were landowners and/or rulers, and were not wealthy due to merit.

Note, some commentators claim that humans solely work to maximize profit, but this was not the case for the owner/rulers, who used their surplus profits to be generous to their offspring and relatives, and other "people like us".  The channeling of generosity to a class or ethnicity, creates an inherited advantaged society, and is typical of human behavior.

With the industrial age, the ability to make lots of stuff much more inexpensively than before created a lot more wealth, and therefore the potential for a large amount of excess profits, far more than the world had ever seen before.  The development of farming mechanization, with the mechanisms built in these factories simultaneously created a large excess of working farmers who were now unemployed.  The numbers of farmers vs factory owners meant that the factory owners had a massive advantage in negotiation how much of that excess profit each won in wage negotiations -- leading to a huge spike in the return on factory ownership. An astonish wealthy class of factory owners developed, the era of the "Robber Barons".  Most were actually wealthy due to merit (they were mostly competent workaholics), but their accumulation of wealth was massively in excess of their relative merit.

These early "Robber Barons" followed the landowner/rulers into controlling government for their own benefit.  Anti-union, anti-education, etc laws were common, in both democracies and aristocracies.  This pattern reflects a Marxist insight that government is purchasable -- it tends to act to skew markets in the interest of those with wealth.  The institutional and legal advantages of ownership and rulership, plus selective generosity, then permanently advantaged their NON-meriting relatives and offspring.

In the first few decades of the 20th century, the farms were drained of most of their excess workers, leading to less of a labor surplus in the industrialized countries, and a gradual increase in the negotiating power of workers, and relative increase in wages.  Simultaneously, "leftist" governments reversed course, and benefitted workers over owners.  Unions often were made mandatory, maximum work days and weeks were legislated, and workplace safety rules were regulated.  Many Social Democrat leftists cite these rules as the reason for the increase in wealth of workers in this era.  Marxist reasoning would argue the causation went the other way, the newly wealthy workers used that wealth to capture the government from the Robber Barons, and then used the government for some additional marginal advantaging.

Note, for most of the 20th century, economic disparity DECREASED in industrialized countries, in contradiction of the premise of this question.

That trend of decreasing disparity reversed in the 1980s.  Simultaneously, governments across the industrialized world began "deregulating".  Social Democratic leftists argue the deregulation caused the disparity.  Marxist thinking is that the increasing disparity lead to the wealthy class being more wealthy, so they could recapture government, and use it to advantage themselves more.

If the Marxist approach is correct, then we need some other explanation for the increasing disparity, besides just "capitalism".  So what changed?

My answer -- the 1980s were the start of the digital era.  This was the first decade of microchips. Prior to the microchip revolution, the high cost of N American or N European workers was more than compensated for by lower transport costs from their factories. Microchips allow the most value-added products to be small and easily transportable, so that suppliers don't have much of an advantage being co-located with final product factories.  A days worth of production no longer needed several trains to be transported, but instead could fit in one jet.  The microchip revolution started a landslide of relocation of factories to places that did not have worker shortages, but instead had worker surpluses because the farmers were still on the land.   This destroyed the bargaining advantage of workers vs factory owners, and the owners recaptured most of the excess profit from their workers.

The software revolution has just amplified this trend.  Now, it is not just blue collar factory work that can be relocated to low cost countries, but all labor.  Worker wages, and fraction of excess profits worldwide, are in steep decline.   And worldwide, "rightist" parties are suddenly more wealthy, and are capturing control of governments.

There is a limit to this rebound into inequality.  Once the world is roughly equally industrialized, there will be no steady supply of new places to export factories to, and inequality will start to decrease again.

Comment: "If the Marxist approach is correct..." And if it is not? Since it is not, as your examples proved.

Comment: My examples showed that, while capitalism increases disparity, that effect moderated for a century, before increasing again recently.  I also provided an explanation for this pattern in disparity.  What do these examples show to be INcorrect?

Comment: You could also argue that laws and ownership are spooks and that the nobility were simply a mafia/mobster/criminals however you wanna call them. They had the muscles for extortion and the mix of population density and means of transportation put a limit to their imperialism and thus created feudalism where the mob boss gave up autonomy to underbosses and who then commanded capos and so on. Where the peasantry was locally outnumbers and incapable of organizing in larger factions effectively (lack of transport and communication).

Comment: Then the industrialization changed that in many ways. On the one hand empires were able to increase in size and there were new means to produce incredible wealth outside of extortion... well kinda... it still made use of the laws put in place and kept up by the mobsters while the mobsters were often interested in letting that flourish to gain even more from extortion. Though while muscles and their whole system of propaganda, intimidation and control was limited to local power, capital could roam freely exercising a similar level of power. So over time capital ownership took over the state.

Comment: So the business model changed from localized extortion to ever more global exploitation of the respective producers. It no longer really mattered where you are or where your profit is coming from it only matters that it keeps coming. And if the state is a universal institution enabling your business model and the people themselves uphold it, then you don't have to BE the state you just have to assert just enough influence to make it stay the way it is or move slightly in your favor. Again better transportation, communication, infrastructure and universal infrastructure and so on.

Comment: Likewise population density grew, so did education, organization and access to resources while imprisonment, propaganda and intimidation became more difficult to uphold. Meaning they often were a force of their own and at the end of the 19th century the idea of "simply crush them" no longer seemed feasible or at least as easy as it used to be. So governments either changed or were changed. Yet instead of dismantling this structure, people thought to use it in their favor. Basically replicating the old regimes with new themes.

Comment: So with any kind of organized crime, at a certain point you reach a size where it's not just taking stuff from other people but where you actually have to take responsibility because otherwise people simply question your necessity. Like if death in combat is scary, but death through starvation is more scary. So yes as long as there was a specter of even peasants being able to overthrow their oppressors those oppressors had to justify their existence and buy their support at ever higher prices reducing inequality.

Comment: @haxor789 Your "explanation" does not explain the recent rise in inequality in the industrialized nations. The economic principles of surplus profit, treating government policy as purchasable with wealth, and accounting for the cost of transport from intermediate suppliers to final producers explains the concentration of industry in N Europe and N America, the rise and decline of inequality, and the recent rise due to lower transport costs. The "benefit people like me" generosity with surplus profits better explains the sociology of in group control being maintained over time.

Comment: @Dcleve It's not so much that governing policies are purchasable with economic control it's that it's hard to even separate the two in the first place. Like you can be the king of a country and it means nothing if you are not able to exercise economic and military control. While having access to key military or economic resources and positions can mean lots of power even if it is not officially recognized. Like you don't have to bribe the government if you control the industry that makes up the majority of it's revenue then that alone is power that can be leveraged even with moral government.

Comment: @Dcleve So the question is on whom does the current business model rely and the more people that are the more you can decrease inequality, while position that let you effectively force society into a bottleneck that you control allows for rampant inequality. However perfect inequality is not sustainable, as you'd have EVERYBODY against you so you usually need to buy favors with other people, but that doesn't have to mean being generous to people like you. It's probably just convenient to find scapegoat groups because otherwise people would be aware that it could be them next time.

Comment: @Dcleve But you don't have to rely on this idea of competitive relations and domination and in fact it's quite inefficient so if we could overcome that, we might also find ways to get around that vicious cycle.

Comment: @haxor789 -- market economics provides a problem case for our morality.  1) market economies outperform command economies.  2) Simple "market is best" rationalizations are untrue -- infrastructure, externalities, monopoly behavior, and the purchasing the government refute this.  3) We therefore need a mixed economic model, with regulation and some government provided sectors where externalities are high.  4) But we are bad at understanding how to regulate, so lots of unintended consequences/inefficiencies.  And 5) the oligarchs use inefficiencies to justify institutionalizing inequality.

Comment: We saw in the 90s and early 2000s, when tech companies lost several key regulation votes in congress decisively, that $ don't automatically lead to power.  It takes an intentional effort on the part of the wealthy to influence government.  IE, they must allocate a portion of their wealth to purchase government.  Tech companies made a deliberate choice after that to allocate resources to political influencing, and have rolled back most of those early votes/regulations.

Comment: @Dcleve 1. Next to no company or country can be as volatile or better erratic as "the market", meaning they all employ (central) planning to some extend. 2. Market economies apparently drive inequality so there are a huge number of people for whom they don't outperform anything. Like if you are a rich country, not in risk of being invaded and/or supplier of requested resources then this works for you because you extract resources from everywhere and still improve your position. Which might have snowballing effects. While if you are poor and only able to supply low demand goods because of that

Comment: @Dcleve then you're basically screwed and entrapped in a system that is pretty similar to colonialism. So no it's not just the fact that no market is ever free and open, but that industrial nations restrict the export of high tech goods, that countries that don't want to open their resources to the market are forced to (by military means if necessary) or are excluded from the exchange of resources. Or that there is a lot of infrastructure provided by the collective of the citizens that is just taken for granted.  It's also that the system is far from working universally for everyone.

Comment: @Dcleve Similar to the nature of scientific revolutions you have periods of incremental growth where you have either small improvements due to experience and research or consolidations of power for those in possession of the relevant resources and means of production and you have periods where a new technology or resource takes the cake and where you've got a disruption of the current system. But while the actors may change the system largely stays the same unless social pressure and ethical decisions try to counter these inherent market failures.

Comment: @Dcleve Though sure even then you have the choice between treating people as equal or making up a peer group and arguing that it's fine as long as that peer group is accounted for and the rest is screwed over. Yet that approach leads to long lasting and bloody conflict and usually that peer group is getting ever smaller and most people that are told to defend it are never really part of it to begin with...

Answer (score -1):

This question makes unclear, unstated and false assumptions about moral philosophy, political economy and the conduct of politicians. So to reply to this question it is necessary to address those assumptions.

So let's start with the assumptions about moral philosophy:

> Yes, the quality of life of ordinary man has gone better as compared to one century before, but from Korea to US, Germany to Australia, gap between rich and poor is getting wider and wider.

This statement assumes that you should care about what other people have and feel a burning envy and resentment if they have more. It isn't enough to say that some people do feel such resentment, because if that's all there was to it you could advise the envious person to change his ideas so he will stop envying people. Basing your life around what other people do is a mistake because it makes you dependent on them. But other people don't control you and most of them don't know much about you. So their ability to help you is extremely limited. Should they give you more money if you have less money? Not necessarily, maybe you have less money because you suck at dealing with money.

There is another much uglier side to this envy. The idea that rich people owe poor people assumes that rich people owe stuff to poor people by virtue of having more money. In other words, a rich person are just an end to be used by a poor person. If he doesn't do what the poor person wants, he is bad and should be expropriated or punished in some other way.

There is a common idea that rich people get rich unfairly. There are two ways to get lots of money in our current political system. One is to sell stuff that makes a profit. When this happens, the material used to make the goods cost less than the goods themselves. The goods used to makes the sales goods (capital goods) could be demanded for other uses, but the person who actually uses them outbids the person who doesn't. He is willing to pay more because he judges them more suitable than the alternatives and he makes enough money to bid for them. So the other potential users have less demand for those capital goods. If there was a better use for those goods from the point of view of consumers it would be possible for somebody to work that out and outbid the current highest bidder. So problems with how things are made can be corrected by the system of profit and loss. All of the transactions involved are voluntary - a person who doesn't want to undertake them won't be forced to undertake them.

The other way people can make money is getting favours from government officials, including politicians. Government officials get their income by having the ability to use force against people who haven't initiated the use of force against them. For example, if I judge that my tax money is being wasted for purpose X and I write to the government and say "I don't agree with X and won't pay for it", then the government will not take no for an answer. I will be forced to pay or I will be imprisoned and if I resist then I may be injured or killed.

Selling stuff to make a profit is a rational way to get resources since it facilitates the correction of errors. In politics, correcting errors is a lot harder. In Western countries, where correcting political errors is easiest, at best you get the ability to cast a single vote every few years and if the government you voted for loses you a load of policies you disagree with are foisted on you. And since politicians have such poor feedback about what they're doing, they make many mistakes.

To understand these issues better you could read "The Virtue of Selfishness" or "Atlas Shrugged" by Ayn Rand, [Capitalism](https://mises.org/library/capitalism-treatise-economics) by George Reisman or [Interventionism: An Economic Analysis](https://mises.org/library/interventionism-economic-analysis) by Ludwig von Mises.

Comment: Your presumption that profit always follows virtue is not supported by the actual world data.  There are multiple subtleties to market systems which Austrian economists ignore, but non-Austrians account for, including surplus profit, monopsomy, monopoly fraction, the payoff to deceit/cheating, the ability to purchase the government, the irrationality of human decision making, and the sociology of human behavior.

Comment: "This statement assumes that you should care about what other people have and feel a burning envy and resentment if they have more." No, it really doesn't. There is no assumption of "burning envy and resentment" implicit in a statement of fact. It is a fact that there is a wealth gap, and it is a fact that that gap is increasing.

Comment: It is *not* a fact that the gap is increasing. I posted the data.  You commented on my answer. You have no excuse for this falsehood.

Comment: @philosodad Your question sez wealth inequality is a problem. It's not. What you're implicitly assuming in your question is that we should focus on how much wealth people have, when, as explained in the answer, what matters is how people got the wealth. Getting wealth by govt favours makes businessmen less accountable and that should be opposed. Getting wealth by providing stuff people want without govt favours is good and should be supported.

Comment: @BillOnne -- no, you posted a LINK, then made false assertions about the data in the link.  The Gini coefficient has increased over the period you claim it has declined.

Comment: @alanf it isn't my question, it doesn't assume it's a "problem" (only that left wing parties think it is a problem), and even if it did make that assumption, it does not follow that it is a problem because I should resent other people. Whether something is or is not a problem is independent of my feelings.

Comment: @BillOnne Correlation is not causation, and your supposed trend does not hold over the last 30 or so years. https://www.pewresearch.org/social-trends/2020/01/09/trends-in-income-and-wealth-inequality/

Comment: @philosodad I posted a link to 200 years of data. You cherry picked. There is no excuse for your falsehood.

Comment: @BillOnne you posted two links. According to one, the Gini coefficient is higher now than it was 200 years ago. According to the other, it isn't. You've cherry picked what data you think is relevant. It is a fact that, in the United States, over the last several decades, wealth inequality has increased. According to the wikipedia link you posted, worldwide, over the last 200 years, wealth inequality has increased. It is a fact that, according to your link, the recent worldwide decline in wealth inequality is not due to capitalism, but to increased social services and progressive taxation.

Comment: @philosodad  Nope. https://www.gapminder.org/tools/#$model$markers$line$data$filter$dimensions$country$country$/$in@=usa&=chn&=rus&=fin&=dnk&=nor;;;;;;&encoding$y$data$concept=gini&source=fasttrack&space@=country&=time;;&scale$type:null&domain:null&zoomed:null;;;;;;&chart-type=linechart&url=v1

Comment: The countries that have been applying progressive taxes and social services have seen about 50 years of increasing Gini coeff.

Comment: @BillOnne Whatever. All you've done here is made an assertion and reposted the source that agrees with you, while ignoring your own source that disagrees with you.

Comment: @Dcleve "Austrian economists ignore... surplus profit" What's "surplus profit"? "monopsomy" [False.](https://cdn.mises.org/journals,scholar,block12.pdf) "monopoly" [False.](https://mises.org/austrian-school/monopoly-and-competition) "deceit/cheating" As in fraud? "the ability to purchase the government" [False.](https://mises.org/library/who-captures-whom-case-regulation) "the irrationality of human decision making" In what sense? "the sociology of human behavior" Extremely vague.

Answer (score -2):

No. Inequality is not even particularly related to capitalism. And to the extent that it is, it is very weakly negatively correlated.

Note that nearly all of the countries one might think of as capitalist today are far from purely so. The [USA for example](https://www.oecd.org/tax/revenue-statistics-united-states.pdf) collects approximately 25.5 % of the GDP as taxes. Government sets the rules, monitors the results, and actively particpates in large swathes of the economy. This is hardly pure capitalism.

One measure of wealth inequality is the [Gini coefficient.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) "A Gini coefficient of 0 expresses perfect equality, where all values are the same, while a Gini coefficient of 1 (or 100%) expresses maximal inequality among values. "

The data pictured here is from https://www.gapminder.org/tools/ with the Gini coefficient chosen as the vertical. It is a bit of a challenge to decide what to put as the horizontal axis.  What will represent the "degree of capitalism" in a country? The graph has chosen Democracy score. This is described as "Overall polity score from the Polity IV dataset, calculated by subtracting an autocracy score from a democracy score. It is a summary measure of a country's democratic and free nature."  Freedom is taken as a proxy for capitalism.

[image]

If you are not familiar with Gapminder, this graph may appear quite strange. The data is from the best available sources, all cited and vetted on the web site. The data is available to download from the site. The data points are shown in this graph with the size of the ball indicating the population of the country. Green is north and south America, Yellow is Europe and the former USSR, blue is Africa, red is Asia and Australia.

There is no particular trend here. The scatter at a given democracy score is similar to that across the whole range. Democracy and freedom do no better and no worse at producing equality of wealth than does autocracy.

[This](https://www.gapminder.org/tools/#$model$markers$bubble$encoding$y$data$concept=gini&source=fasttrack&space@=country&=time;;&scale$domain:null&zoomed:null&type:null;;&x$data$concept=democracy_score_use_as_color&space@=country&=time;;&scale$domain:null&zoomed:null&type:null;;&frame$value=2011;;;;;&chart-type=bubbles&url=v1) is the link to the data tool with the setup I used. It is interesting to play the animation from the begining of the data set at about the year 1800. Nearly all the movement is horizontal with just a little motion vertical, very gently downward. That is, over the last two centuries as capitalism has made limited penetration, the Gini coefficient has changed only very weakly, and that very slightly downward.

That's right. The world with capitalism has very slightly less inequality than it did two centuries ago when capitalism was first spreading.

Indeed, the notion that inequality is uniquely associated with or created by capitalism is simply wrong. Inequality has existed since humans have existed. And it has existed under every political system humans have ever invented.

Comment: Comments are not for discussing political agendas.